# Find max and last value from a googlesheet query skipping x rows

Tags: sql, google-sheets, select

I have a data set in google sheets, for each week of data I have 3 rows. I wish to query the data in every second row to calculate the max value and the last value.

For instance:

| ROW | DATA |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 800 |
| 2 | Text |
| 3 | 500 |
| 4 | More text |
| 5 | 600 |
| 6 | Blah |
| 7 | 700 |
| 8 | Blah |

For Max value I have the following which will return 800

```
MAX(FILTER(QUERY(A1:A,"Select * skipping 2"), QUERY(A1:A,"Select * skipping 2") <> 0))
```

How do I change it up to return the last value? Which should return 700

Comment: It's worth stating that MAX ignores cells containing text strings, so your formula for calculating the max could just be =MAX(range) - no need to skip the text cells.

Comment: It looks as though you could just put =index(A:A,counta(A:A)-1) for the last one?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=LOOKUP(2^99,FILTER(A:A,A:A<>0))
```

- 

[image]

Comment: How would I change that to read every nth row? n^99?

Comment: Can you maybe explain a bit more citing the above sample data on whats the end goal that needs to be achieved here?!

Comment: So I have simplified the sheet a lot for this. The other columns don't contain text, but numbers I wish to ignore. There may be other data I wish to add per weekly set so the number of rows I want to ignore could potentially increase which is why I need to sample the data every nth number of rows.

Comment: it would help if you could share a sample demo sheet recreating this scenario so that we can check it out directly and work it out.

Answer (score 2):

@rockinfreakshow answer will successfully find the last number.

To filter a range by n amount of rows, you can use:

```
=FILTER(A:A,MOD(ROW(A:A),n)=1)
```

Change n with your desired value, and 1 with the number of row you want to get. 1 for the first, 2 for the second, but 0 if you want the nth one. To find MAX, just wrap it in MAX()

To find the last one, even if it's a text or number, you can use SORTN and SEQUENCE:

```
=SORTN(FILTER(A:A,MOD(ROW(A:A),n)=1,A:A<>""),1,1, SEQUENCE(COUNTA(FILTER(A:A,MOD(ROW(A:A),n)=1,A:A<>""))),0)
```

It orders the elements in reverse order and only chooses the first one

Remember to change n with the number of rows and =1 with the number of row you want to choose